# How does Amazon ask for so many permissions on Facebook on one screen?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I'm working on a Facebook app that requires a few basic permissions (email, birthday, etc) as well as publish_actions (so I can create stories about user interaction).

When I ask for these permissions, the end user is presented with one screen for the basic permissions and yet another for the publish_actions permission.

However, when I looked at the following app from Amazon:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/socialmedia/promotions/SprngSweep

When I click on the enter button, I am redirected to Facebook to ask for permissions (as expected), however, they have all their permissions one page *(Amazon would like to access your public profile, friend list, email address, birthday, photos, videos, personal description, likes and your friends' birthdays and likes. Amazon would like to post on your behalf. Amazon would like to access your data at any time.)*

*I can't add a picture due to lack of rep*

The url that I'm redirect to is this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=164734381262&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.co.uk%2Fgp%2Fsocialmedia%2Ffbr%2Fconnect-handler.html%2Fref%3Dfbr_hn_SprngSweep%3Fie%3DUTF8%26appName%3DAmazon%26externalApp%3DKindle%26onSuccess%3D%252Fgp%252Fsocialmedia%252Fpromotions%252FSprngSweep%253Fie%253DUTF8%2526sm-sweeps_submit%253D1%2526sm-sweeps_submit.x%253D66%2526sm-sweeps_submit.y%253D20%2526sweepsConnect%253D1%2526sweepsEligibility%253D1%26ref%3DSprngSweep%26token%3D6CBF36BD25311891B2F205333EFA3AA78E561AB9&scope=
```

While attempting to investigate this myself, I noticed that they aren't even passing a value for `scope` in the url.

How the hell are they doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely they are using an old API (FB changed the behavior over there recently, read their blogs please) or they are using hidden features which FB created for them (as this has an impact on there advertising revenue obviously, and even these guys are "coin operated").

The "two pager" is normal, FB API and FB advertising API quit the same. I wouldn't worry.